# Kotlin compiling from command line

Tags: command-line, path, compilation, kotlin

I need to compile some Kotlin files and run them as described at [Kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/command-line.html)

However, my command line keeps saying this:

> C:\Users\name\Documents\Projec\Kotlin>kotlinc
> 'kotlinc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

I am a 64-bit Windows 7 user.
So I downloaded the latest version of the compiler (1.0.6 ATM) and extracted the files into my Program Files folder.

My variable path is set like this:

> PATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin; C:\Program Files\kotlinc\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools;

At this point I have no idea, I tried two versions of the compiler and tried changing the path variable few times.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Windows PATH is semicolon-delimited; white space is *not* trimmed.

You need to remove the space between `;` and `C:\Program Files\kotlinc\bin\` in order for the directory to be added correctly to PATH.