# Kotlin and vs code

Tags: java, kotlin, visual-studio-code

I start learning kotlin .when I run the code on vs code it shows that "kotlinc is not recognized as an internal or external command ,oreable program or batch file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kotlin compiling from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41511497/kotlin-compiling-from-command-line)

Comment: Download kotlin-compiler-1.4.21.zip from [link](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/releases/tag/v1.4.21), extract it to C:\Program Files\kotlinc, then add C:\Program Files\kotlinc\bin\ to your system environmental path